# Retrieve Data from Broken Screen P30 Lite? Keyboard Steps to Enable ADB?

Tags: data-recovery, huawei

My father's phone, a Huawei P30 Lite, has had the screen completely ruined by his insistence of putting it in his back pocket and then sitting on the thing.

I'm sure I enabled developer mode at some point but did not enable usb debugging. Nor has it been set to have file transfer as the default USB mode.

I have a USB-C hub with a HDMI output but can't convince it to work, not sure it's supported on this model.
*However*, I can connect a keyboard and mouse and unlock the phone (I can see a blur of colour that changes when I enter the pin correctly), though I can't see the screen to access the settings app unless someone can test it out on a working device and provide me the exact keyboard inputs to navigate to developer settings in order to enable USB debugging, OR enable HDB so I can just use HiSuite. (or worst-case, enable dev-settings too)

Alternatively if it's quicker, casting to a FireStick?

Annoyingly with the tools I have I cannot simultaneously connect a keyboard and connect to a PC, otherwise I'd just arrow key my way to selecting file-transfer mode on the pop-up. If I had a USB-C hub with a USB-C data port on it (this one does not) could I run that extra port to my laptop and get the pop-up whilst still having the KB+M input to the phone? Could I emulate a KB+M with some nonsense on my PC?

Open to any alternatives at all, including flashing custom recovery software that will talk to my computer, if at all possible in its current state.

Oh and I can't ADB in recovery mode without already having enabled it in normal boot.

Thank you *very* kindly!!

Comment: best is to try keyboard on working phone. once you figured out you can use bluetooth keyboard to confirm usb connection

Comment: @alecxs oh I'm using a physical keyboard I'll never get a bluetooth device connected to this thing, that said I managed to find a still-working Huawei device of a similar age and use the keyboard to get the notifications open and access the USB settings notification, switching to file-transfer mode, so I can retrieve data! 
The settings app is unfortunately just not very good at handling keyboard inputs, though I may well be able to use a desktop with his login to get an app that takes you directly to the Developer Mode settings and use the "just installed" notification to access it

Comment: right, but you need bluetooth keyboard at some point. you can authorize it with a screenshot

Comment: ...Why would I need a BT keyboard? Regardless I got the data I need without.

Comment: ... to authorize adb connection

Comment: Oh right, whilst connected to my computer. I get you. Not sure how I'd manage to connect to the BT keyboard honestly, the steps are too convoluted. Probably going to just remote wipe it and send it for trade-in/scrap